# What is efficiency of key=dictionary.get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, min

I have a dictionary and I'd like to find elegant and effective way of finding a `key:value` pair where the value is minimal across the dictionary (one of the minimal, if many exist). Apart from obvious `for` loop approaches I've found several others in StackOverflow:

1st approach:

```
  temporary = [x for x in myDictionary.items()] # list is created just for using sorted()
  foundKey, minimalValue = sorted(temporary, key=lambda x: x[1]) [0]
```

2nd approach:

```
  minimalValue = min(myDictionary.values())
  foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.get)
```

The 2nd runs little bit faster for myDictionary of thousands items, but ...I cannot find explanation of the `key=myDictionary.get` construct. Isn't it possible to join two min's into one `foundKey, minimalValue = ...` ?

Comment: why not use something like `foundKey, minimalValue = min(myDictionary.items(), key = lambda x:x[1])`?

Comment: Great advice for me  in the meantime I edited my question and just found your answer for it!  Anyway, what is 'get' in 'key=myDictionary.get' ? I know only 'get()' method.

Comment: @mja. You may still consider selecting my answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, or posting your own answer and selecting that. Either way, selecting an answer will remove your question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @mja. I've added some timings to my answer. Looks like `__getitem__` as your key is the fastest approach. Enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach can be rephrased better as

```
foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.get)
minValue = myDictionary[foundKey]
```

The method `get` retrieves the value corresponding to the key being inspected so instead of comparing `key1`, `key2`, you are comparing `myDictionary.get[key1]`, `myDictionary.get[key2]`.

You could equally well use `__getitem__`. It will likely be faster, but won't look as pretty:

```
foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.__getitem__)
```

By the way, the first approach has two possible improvements:

```
temporary = list(myDictionary.items())
foundKey, minimalValue = sorted(temporary, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

OR

```
temporary = [x[::-1] for x in myDictionary.items()]
foundKey, minimalValue = min(temporary)
```

OR

```
foundKey, minimalValue = min(zip(myDictionary.values(), myDictionary.keys()))
```

**Timing**

Let's make a dictionary of size `n`:

```
from random import shuffle

values = list(range(n))
shuffle(values)
myDictionary = dict(zip(map('{:08d}'.format, range(n)), values))
```

Timings for `n=10000`:

```
%%timeit
... temporary = [x for x in myDictionary.items()]
... foundKey, minimalValue = sorted(temporary, key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
5.76 ms ± 32.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
... minimalValue = min(myDictionary.values())
... foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.get)
1.85 ms ± 3.57 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So clearly running `min` (`O(n)`) is faster than `sorted` (`O(n log n)`).

```
%%timeit
... foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.get)
... minValue = myDictionary[foundKey]
1.36 ms ± 10.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So running `min` and doing a lookup is faster than running `min` twice.

```
%timeit foundKey, minimalValue = min(zip(myDictionary.values(), myDictionary.keys()))
1.32 ms ± 6.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Running `min` without a lookup is faster yet.

```
%%timeit
... foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.__getitem__)
... minValue = myDictionary[foundKey]
1.27 ms ± 2.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Using `__getitem__` with a lookup is faster still.

**TL;DR**

It seems that the fastest approach of those shown here is

```
foundKey = min(myDictionary, key=myDictionary.__getitem__)
minValue = myDictionary[foundKey]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I did similar measurements inside my complete project, and the results are similar: your fastest approach takes me 48 seconds, and and the similar using `get` in place of `__getitem__` takes 52 seconds (±2 in 4 takes each). I finally selected `get` as it looks nicer for me (since I've understood its meaning) - I'm 72 and _absolute beginner_ in programming ;)

Comment: @mja. It's never too late, and you've definitely got the right approach. I wish more people just benchmarked things for their own projects. By the way, dunder (short for double underscore) methods implement operators for python objects. `__getitem__` is the `[...]` indexing operator used by dictionaries and lists. The biggest difference between `get` and `__getitem__` is that one returns `None` and the other raises a `KeyError` when a key name is missing.